# CABasicAnimation resets after completion

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, cabasicanimation, quartz-core

Yeah I know this was an issue in a lot of questions but I still cant get it working.

My function moves all the subviews on the view.
This is how it looks like:

```
- (void)moveTo:(NSInteger)side
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    animation.duration = 0.8f;
    animation.autoreverses = NO;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];

    switch (side)
    {
        case kMovementSideDown: animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:568]; break;
        case kMovementSideUp: animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-568]; break;
    }


    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        [[view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform.translation.y"];
    }
}
```

And I know this moves all items outside on 4 inch screen, its what I want.
But after it moves items outside they "jump" back inside despite I set the `removedOnCompletion = 0` flag. I have also tried overriding the delegate method and setting the position manually after completion but with no luck.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're animating `transform` property of a layer, you should check what else could reset it to `CATransform3DIdentity` (default) state. But why not use simple `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` method to animate view's frame?

Comment: How can I accomplish the same thing by using `animateWithDuration`? I am doing animations for the first time and this is what I found first.

Comment: `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f animations:^{
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame,0,568);
    }
}];`

Comment: I strongly recommend using the standard `UIView` block-based animations before starting Core Animation. CA has several gotchas and has more power than you probably want right now.

Comment: Can I ask you something? How can I (if possible) use this on a scroll view? My idea is to put some buttons in a scroll view (horizontally) and when user scrolls a little I calculate the offset and animate it to the nearest "center" so that the button would be in the middle of the scroll view. Can this be accomplished? I would much appreciate it if you could show me how.

Comment: You don't have to calculate the offset of `UIScrollView`'s content, just use `scrollView.contentOffset` property.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "end" position of the **layer** before you start animation in order for it not to jump back.

```
[yourView layer].position = endPos;
```